# Using java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit shows GroovyBugError on JMETER

Tags: java, selenium, groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am currently using JMETER with plugin for Selenium Web Driver Sampler. Why is this happening? any solution I can use so that I can use implicit wait, explicit wait, and fluent wait?

Here is my code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.time.*;
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('[mywebsite]')
WebDriver driver = WDS.browser;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30)
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);


var timeunit = java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

ERROR encountered
2022-03-22 06:04:08,501 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-1,6,main]
org.codehaus.groovy.GroovyBugError: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'Script69.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 61
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$ISourceUnitOperation.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:905) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:627) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:389) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.lambda$parseClass$3(GroovyClassLoader.java:332) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.compute(StampedCommonCache.java:163) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.getAndPut(StampedCommonCache.java:154) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:330) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:314) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:257) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.getScriptClass(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:336) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:153) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:262) ~[java.scripting:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:86) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
```

Comment: The root cause is `Unsupported class file major version 61`.

Comment: How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Unsupported class file major version 61`

1. Looking [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout) - `Java SE 17 = 61 (0x3D hex)` so you're using Java 17 which was released in [September 2021](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/17/)
2. Looking [here](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/gradle.properties#L86) it seems that the latest [JMeter 5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41) is using Groovy 3.0.7 which was released in [December 2020](https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@groovy.apache.org/msg05542.html)

So my expectation is that you need to downgrade your Java version to something which existed in December 2020 i.e. to [Java 11](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/11/) and the problem should go away. The minimum version you can run [JMeter 5.4](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities)+ is Java 8.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, if all else fails on JMeter 5.5, i'll use your answer for and go back to JMETER5.4